# How to prevent aucomponent table from growing in size so that it changes the size of the component?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, aura, design-patterns

[image]

Hidden Component 3 is a table (not lightning data table.)
It is fetched with some data-- but when the text gets too large (even with truncation), the entire component will grow with the table.

Component 1,2, 3 are encapsulated in a layout and when component 3 gets too big, it, together with its parent component 2, wraps itself under component 1, which is NOT how it should behave.

[image]

How can this be corrected?

Comment: PS. We might need to see some demo code. Consider making an [edit] to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lightning:layout. It supports 12 columns, so you might choose to split them such as 4-8 or 3-9 (etc) to suit your needs.

```
<lightning:layout>
  <lightning:layoutItem size="4">
    <c:component1/>
  </lightning:layoutItem>
  <lightning:layoutItem size="8">
    <c:component2/>
    <c:component3/>
  </lightning:layoutItem>
```

Comment: Thank you SO Much!